# RestSharp deserialize to List<MyClass>

Tags: c#, .net, json, rest, restsharp

I use RestSharp to get json from some page. The response is this:

```
{
    "cars": [
        {
            "name": "car1",
            "size": 10,
            "color": "black"
        },
        {
            "name": "car2",
            "size": 20,
            "color": "white"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have this class for one car:

```
public class Car
    {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public int Size { get; set; }
      public string Color { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I map this response to the list of cars?

If there is not the `"cars":[` in json, it is easy, but now I need to do it like this:

```
private class Cars
    {
      public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    }

    ...

    IRestResponse<Cars> response = client.Execute<Cars>(request);
    ...
    ...response.Data.Cars...
```

but I feel that the class Cars is useless and I want to do something like this:

```
IRestResponse<List<Car>> response = client.Execute<List<Car>>(request);
...
...response.Data...
```

**EDIT:**

This is for the request creating:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(http...));
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
```

Comment: Show us the code where you deserialize

Comment: This is it. The Execute<T>() deserializes it and maps it to the <T> class.

Comment: I think [this](https://www.bytefish.de/blog/restsharp_custom_json_serializer/) is what you want

Comment: @FilipCordas overwritting or next libraries can help, but it is more difficult than just to create the class Cars that I have now, so for this case is also useless.

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar if I put the json to [], will not be it cars[]car[]? I need just car[]. and I dont want to use some external deserializer, because it is more difficult than just to have my Cars class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming there is only one 'cars' array, code below will get the job done.

```
var response = client.Execute<Dictionary<string,List<Car>>>(request);

//You can access cars this way.
var data = response.Data["cars"];
```

Comment: thanks! Based on this idea I tried KeyValuePair<string, List<Car>> but it doesn't work, so I used your solution

Comment: Exactly! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for but i found this way very comfortable when working with json (JSonConvert is in the NewtownSoft.Json package)

```
dynamic dynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
if(dynamicObject.cars != null)
{
    foreach(var car in dynamicObject.cars)
    {
        Car currentCar = new Car();
        If(car.name != null) currentCar.Name= car.name; 
        If(car.size!= null) currentCar.Size= car.size;
        If(car.color!= null) currentCar.Color= car.color;
        myCarList.Add(currentCar);
    }
}
```

Also I think this could be done with less code by:

```
JObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
foreach(var car in obj["cars"])
{
    myCarList.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(car.toString());
}
```